# Define Proj4 string for CANGRD dataset

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, proj

I'm trying to georeference the .grd files provided here http://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/3d4b68a5-13bc-48bb-ad10-801128aa6604.

The documentation states "The CANGRD grid is in polar stereographic projection with a 50 km spatial resolution. The grid is a 125 (columns) by 95 (rows) matrix, where the SW corner (0,0) is at 40.0451°N latitude and 129.8530°W longitude. The projection is true at 60.0°N and centered on 110.0°W."

The header of each .grd file contains this:

```
DSAA
125 95
0.0 124
0.0 94
-3.051277 3.268792
```

I tried with the following Proj4 string, but the whole dataset appears tilted.

```
+proj=stere +lat_0=40.0451 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=-129.8530 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +k=1 +to_meter=50000
```

Any idea how to properly georeference these files?

Comment: You might try lat_0=90 (for polar stereographic) and center longitude for lon_0, and use x_0 and y_0 to get the SW corner right.

Comment: ... Maybe related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116016/geotransformation-for-polar-stereographic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I did what AndreJ suggested and put lat_0=90 to generate this temporary system

```
+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=-110 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +to_meter=50000
```

Then I transformed the latitude, longitude of the corners to this new reference system and used those coordinates to calculate the x_0 and y_0.

```
+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=-110 +x_0=1884770 +y_0=5220000 +datum=WGS84 +to_meter=50000
```

This seems to give a perfect definition for the CANGRID files. Note that in this reference system, the units are "grid cells", or meters/50000

I believe the equivalent WKT .prj file content is:

```
PROJCS["CANGRD_Polar_Stereographic",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Stereographic_North_Pole"],PARAMETER["false_easting",37.6954],PARAMETER["false_northing",104.4],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-110.0],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",60.0],UNIT["50_Kilometers",50000.0]]
```

Comment: To proof the WKT, you can run `gdalsrsinfo` on the .prj file, or a text file with the PROJ.4 definition.

Comment: I tried to use gdalsrsinfo to convert the Proj4 string to WKT, but the result was seen as invalid by ArcGIS. I then copied the parameters individually to the projection definition dialog in Arc and that seemed to work and gave the .prj file above.

Comment: Did you use the `-o wkt_esri` switch of `gdalsrsinfo`? There's a difference in how entities are named.

Comment: @HowardButler I did not know the existence of the switch. Thanks!